# VSCode - Open multiple files from tree view and quick open

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

How to select and open multiple files from tree view (File Explorer) and Quick open in Visual Studio Code? I'm looking for something by which I can shift-up/down or shift-mouseclick to select multiple files and open them on clicking enter.

Is there a setting or extension to enable this?

Comment: there is a feature request and the vs team said they'll implement this in future: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1023

Comment: Oh! Didn't come across that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1.20 (Feb., 2018) adds some of this functionality.  You can now multi-select files https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_multi-select-in-the-explorer and open them in a new editor group to the side and other group functions in the context menu.

---

In v1.47 you can open file after file from the explorer without losing focus on the explorer with a new command:

```
 {
    "key": "alt+u",           // whatever keybinding you wish
    "command": "list.selectAndPreserveFocus",
    "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceReadonly && !inputFocus"

    // "when": "inFilesPicker && inQuickOpen"  // doesn't work in quickOpen
         // but rightArrow does work in the quickOpen panel
  },
```

Comment: Any idea how to open multiple files from Quick Open window as well?

Comment: Thank you! I never expected it to work that way. I was looking for something on the lines of how Jetbrains does it with its IDE's.