# VSCode Command Palette (Crtl P) Open Multiple Files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to open multiple files from the Crtl P (Command Palette). I.e. shift + arrow keys, or crtl click multiple files.

This functionality is available in Jet brains IDE products, would be very helpful.

Comment: Just `RightArrow` on any file you want to open.  The "file picker" quickOpen will stay open and you can keep opening other files.

Comment: Or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004686/vscode-open-multiple-files-from-tree-view-and-quick-open from the file explorer